# Assigning an element an id when document is loaded so it can perform a different function when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipulate an `id` to use the same button to do more then 2 actions.

its something like:

```
var id;
if(something == 2){
   id = "id";
}else{
   id = "id2";
}

$(".myClass").attr("id", id);
```

but, its not good, because if i try to use the `id` that i set, won't work, maybe because the document was already loaded with no `id` in the button.

dont think this need a example, [but i made it](http://jsfiddle.net/SWZMd/15/).

have another way to do this ?

Comment: Changing the ID works, but you are trying to bind the event handler **before** the element has the ID. jQuery can only find an element with a certain ID if it exists. Bind the handler when you changed the ID or use event delegation.

Comment: Use google chrome's console to find the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to bind actions to some *future* element, it's generally best to use delegation, meaning to listen for the events not on the elements themselves, but on one of their ancestors:

```
$("body").on("click", "#id2", function(){
    alert( "Clicked!" );
});
```

At this point, you can set the ID dynamically:

```
$(".myClass").attr("id", function(){
    return something === 2
        ? "id" 
        : "id2" ;
});
```

While I am listening for the click event on the body, it's generally best to use a closer parent element so the event doesn't have to bubble too much before being handled.

Comment: funny that i try this, and didin't work, and more funny than that its because i miss the `#`, any way.. lol.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#alertMe', function(){
   alert('Working'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#alertMe").live("click",function(){
   alert('Working'); 
});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'click()' to bind the handler, use live:

```
$("#alertMe").live('click', function(){
   alert('Working'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `click` method is a one time deal. It adds the click event to that id at the point it runs. To dynamically handle click event on that id use `on` like this:

```
$(".button1").click(function(){
    $(".button2").attr("id", "alertMe");
});

$(document).on('click',"#alertMe", function(){
   alert('Working');
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/SWZMd/17/

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the click after you set the id:

```
$(".button1").click(function(){
    $(".button2").attr("id", "alertMe");
    $("#alertMe").click(function(){
      alert('Working'); 
    });

});
```

Comment: The code above is the code the OP posted to jsfiddle.  I just made a change so it would work to answer his question.  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/xKg4m/1/

Comment: Also, i'd personally use a data attribute like data-id but that wasn't what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Move second click event into the first click event, then it will work.

```
$(".button1").click(function(){
   $(".button2").attr("id", "alertMe");
   $("#alertMe").click(function(){
   alert('Working'); 
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dcai/SWZMd/18/